# Displaying Html.ActionLink and text on the same line, if some conditions are true

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I display an Html.ActionLink and a text on the same line with if's conditions? To be more clear, I have this piece of code:

```
@if (Model.StatusID == 3)
            {                
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("A", "B", "CheckOut", new { id = Model.ID, returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }, null)</p>  
            }
```

and in the immediate right of the CheckOut link, I would like to have the word "abc" only if a condition is true.

I tried using `<td></td>`, but I doesn't let me, because all that is inside a div.
Also, I tried to use `<text></text>`, but without a good result.
Thank you!

Comment: So depending on a condition, you want to create a dynamic controller name (CheckOut A or CheckOut B, or CheckOut C)??

Comment: have you tried `<p style="display: inline;">`?

Comment: thank you, it finally worked with    @if (!Model.condition) { <text> | abc </text>}</p>